# Rock, Paper, Scissors: Unsure of how to randomize a choice then add an if-then statement

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, random

I'm pretty new to Python and an working on this homework assignment. I'm not sure how to assign the random.choice to a variable so I can proceed with a if-then statement.

```
import random

def whoWin():
 if userInput == choices

def main():

 userInput = input("rock, paper, or scissor?")
 print "You chose: " + userInput

choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

print "The computer chose: " + (random.choice(choices))

main()
```

Comment: Note that `print` followed immediately by a string is only supported in Python 2, which will be deprecated by the end of this year.  The Python 3 equivalent is `print("You chose: " + userInput)`.  In your serious Python work, remember to wrap the parameter of `print` in parentheses.  Also, check whether the indenting matches the intent of your code.

Comment: You just need to do `compInput = random.choice(choices)` @coolsocks, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as `compInput = random.choice(choices)`, which means assign the value obtained from `random.choice(choices)` to variable `compInput`, which you can use for further usage

In addition, `input` is used in `Python 3`, for `Python 2`, we use `raw_input`

So the code changes to

```
import random

userInput = raw_input("rock, paper, or scissor?")
print("You chose: " + userInput)

choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

#Assign random choice to variable
compInput = random.choice(choices)

print("The computer chose: " + compInput)

#If-else statement goes here
```

The output will be

```
rock, paper, or scissor?rock
You chose: rock
The computer chose: scissors
```